# Adding a newline in the caption of a PlantUML object changes the font

Tags: plantuml

I have the following PlantUML file:

```
@startuml

!include <awslib/AWSCommon>
!include <awslib/AWSSimplified.puml>
!include <awslib/Compute/all.puml>
!include <awslib/NetworkingAndContentDelivery/all.puml>

rectangle "Intermediary VPC" {
  ELBNetworkLoadBalancer(NLB, "NLB", "")
  VPCEndpoints(VPCEndpointService, "VPC endpoint service", "")
}

VPCEndpointService -> NLB

@enduml
```

My problem is that the "VPC endpoint service" caption takes more horizontal space than I'd like, so I added a line break:

```
VPCEndpoints(VPCEndpointService, "VPC endpoint\nservice", "")
```

It worked, but "VPC endpoint" is a certain font size and bolded by default, whereas for some reason the word "service" is now a smaller font size and unbolded. I worked around it by doing this:

```
VPCEndpoints(VPCEndpointService, "VPC endpoint\n<size:16><b>service</b></size>", "")
```

Now there's the line break I wanted, and the word "service" is the same font size as "VPC endpoint", and is bolded.

But it feels like there should be a better way of doing this. Am I missing something? Thanks :)

Comment: This is all related to a behavior (bug?) that is in PlantUML for a long time. Whenever a `\n` is encountered, the Creole style is disabled. This might be a feature so start/end tags don't have to be balanced. It's extra strange in your case because those macros hide the `<size:16><b>` that is part of the formatting that is generated in the pre-processing. You could ask about this in https://forum.plantuml.net/

Comment: That is odd. Thanks for letting me know!